# How to change css style in WatiN?

Tags: css, watin

How can I change css style in WatiN test? Using any script or by other mean?

Comment: Also note WatiN is for reading a web pages information, not changing them directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change how a page gets rendered, look at Fiddler.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

You can run java script that changes the CSS [for example](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/changing_css_using_javascript.htm)

In order to run the script in watin use this command

```
Browser.Eval("Your script that changes the css");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change style of an element, try this:

```
var browser = new IE(true);

IEElement myElement = browser.ElementWithTag("div", Find.ById("myDivID")).NativeElement as IEElement;
myElement.SetStyleAttributeValue("width", "400px");
myElement.SetStyleAttributeValue("height", "600px");
```